# Create Setup file for WPF Project

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, wpf, setup-project

I have designed an application for my client in Visual Studio 2017 (.Net Framework 4.6.1.) using Sql Server Standard version and Crystal Reports. Now I want to create a setup file for client.

1. Do I have to install Sql Server or Sql Server Express on client machine?
2. Do I have to install Crystal Report Runtime on client machine?

I've read lots of similar questions. What is the best way for doing this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> Do I have to install Sql Server or Sql Server Express for client?

No, but maybe you need a [client driver](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36434), if it's not already installed.

> Do I have to install Crystal Report Runtime for client?

Normally, yes, [see this article for example](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/expression/en-US/8ad65b1d-811a-43d2-93fd-0463cac4aa4e/crystal-reports-error-on-client-pc)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is what does "for client" really mean. If your app internally uses a SQL DB to store data for its own purposes then you're installing SQL for your app to work, SQL Lite or Express, and nothing about this internal design detail is exposed to your clients. Similarly, if your app uses Crystal Reports to generate reports then it's for your app, not for the client.

However if your app is offering a service to clients who already have a SQL DB and your app is designed to query or update that database then you do not need to install SQL, you basically need just to allow the client to enter a connection dialog to connect to their existing database. In any case, you cannot install SQL Server because it's a licensed product that you can't install on behalf of the client.

Any more detailed questions about how to do things will depend on which install tool you use to build the setup